# Проблемы с реализацией стека в C

Tags: c, массивы, память, стек, неопределённое-поведение

Есть код стека:

```
typedef struct {
    char stack[32];
    int current;
} char_stack;

void push(char_stack* stackn, char value) {
    stackn->stack[stackn->current] = value;
    stackn->current++;
}

char pop(char_stack* stackn) {
    stackn->current--;
    char c = stackn->stack[stackn->current];
    free(&stackn->stack[stackn->current]);
    return c;
}

int isEmpty(char_stack* stackn) {
    return stackn->current == 0;
}

void print_stack(char_stack* stackn) {
    for (int i = 0; i < stackn->current; i++) {
        printf("    %d %d ", i, stackn->current);
        printf("%c     ", stackn->stack[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Если выполнить код:

```
char_stack* st = (char_stack*) malloc(sizeof(char_stack));
st->current = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 32; i++) {
    st->stack[i] = '.';
}
printf("%d", st->current);
```

То current становится равен 46 (!), что странно, ибо функции, где current должна меняться, не запускались. Также, если выполнить:

```
char_stack* st = (char_stack*) malloc(sizeof(char_stack));
st->current = 0;

// Сразу после выполнения цикла current=32, все верно
for (int i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
    push(st, 'f');
}

// После выполнения этой функции current уже равняется 106(!)
push(st, 'f');
// А после выполнения этой, на экран выводится всякий мусор (системные пути и т.д.)
print_stack(st);

return 0;
```

В чем проблема?
Как я понял, суть в том, что я заменяю последний (32) символ массива, который равняется '\0'. Если это так, то не понимаю, почему замена терминального нуля меняет и переменную current?

Comment: С ходу, совет, если память выделять `calloc` то `st->current = 0;` не понадобиться, да и лишнего мусора не будет. И ошибка тут `for (int i = 0; i <= 32; i++) ` надо `for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) ` вы выходите за массив и портите память, дальше разбираться без смысла, что он там показует.

Comment: И `stackn->current++;` заменить на версию с контролем: `stackn->current = ((stackn->current < sizeof(stackn->stack)) ? (stackn->current + 1) : 0);` и получаем в результате ring buffer :) с уменьшителем примерно так-же надо поступить в функции `pop`.

Comment: Ох, и правда, не заметил, что current, по сути, выходит за пределы... Спасибо!
Но все-таки, вопрос лишь из желания разобраться, почему выход за пределы массива меняет и другие переменные?

Comment: И что там делает `free(..)` в pop !? с таким кодом, результатом будет мусор, он как правило имеет в себе разные невзаимосвязанные значения :)

Comment: free очищает (по крайней мере, так подразумевается :)) память, занятую последним элементом. Что здесь не так?

Comment: Вы выделяете память на всю структуру, а пытаетесь удалить статический массив, память которому динамически отдельно не выделялась. По сути, именно это действие более разрушительное чем выход за пределы массива :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В структуре для хранения элементов выделен массив, имеющий `32` элемента.

```
char stack[32];
```

Следовательно, допустимый диапазон индексов для элементов массива - `[0 - 31]`.

В этом цикле вы пытаетесь занести в стек 33 элемента

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 32; i++) {
//              ^^^^^^                  
    st->stack[i] = '.';
}
```

Поэтому имеет место неопределенное поведение программы, и, похоже, что в результате (выхода за пределы массива) переписывается значение поля `current` ASSCI кодом символа `'.'`, который равен `46`.
Правильно было бы записать

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
//              ^^^^^^                  
    st->stack[i] = '.';
}
```

Аналогичная ситуация с неопределенным поведением программы возникает и после этого фрагмента кода

```
// Сразу после выполнения цикла current=32, все верно
for (int i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
    push(st, 'f');
}

// После выполнения этой функции current уже равняется 106(!)
push(st, 'f');
```

Имейте также в виду, что данное предложение

```
free(&stackn->stack[stackn->current]);
```

некорректное, так как элементы массива не были выделены с помощью функций динамического выделения памяти. Следует удалить это предложение из функции.